# What is the maximum size of an array in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What would be the maximum recommended size for an array field in an elasticsearch document? I am looking into using a document field in order to keep a list of the IDs of "followers" of a user, in order to boost the document in the query results when the user executing the query is following a potential match.

Also, is there perhaps a better way to improve the relevance of a user document than this rather brutal approach?

Comment: so how much followers will one person have?

Comment: For the beginning, not too many - like hundreds at most